# binary is whitelisted installin from live-cd win8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, asus

i'm trying to install ubuntu 12.04.2 64bit on a asus k55n running a preinstalled win8.
the bios (of uefi o this computer) are set to load from UEFI usb device, the fast boot is disabled and the "launch CSM" that is a similar to secure booting is also disabled.
the grub window opens (gnu grub version 1.99-2 ubuntu3.9 ) with the regular 3 options (try with out install, install, check disk for errors) but any option i choose spit a "binary is whitelisted" , and stop there without booting.

i've look in the ubuntu forum for answers but (even if quite a few asus owner have the similar problems), but as nothing boots i cannot change nomodeset or grub parameters.

i'm really stuck and none af the many posts i read on the subject seems to be usefull...
thank you really much to anyone that can help, Cri

Comment: what did you try to fix the problem ? Did you whitelist the ubuntu efi in your bios as suggested ?

Comment: some machine come with usb 3.0 and ubuntu may not detect them. Try to use a cd or an usb 2.0 port and see if it work. Ubuntu 12.04.2 supported Secure Boot so you don't have to care about it much

Answer (score 0):

First, the "binary is whitelisted" message is displayed by the program that Ubuntu uses to deal with Secure Boot (namely, `shim`); it indicates that the follow-on program (typically GRUB) is properly signed and therefore trusted. There's no need to "whitelist the ubuntu efi in your bios," as bodhi.zazen suggests.

Second, the "launch CSM" option you mention is ***not*** similar to Secure Boot. Under a "bare-bones" EFI implementation, all OSes boot using unsigned EFI boot loaders. The Compatibility Support Module (CSM) and Secure Boot both change this, but in entirely different ways. CSM is just another name for a BIOS emulation layer, aka "legacy boot" mode. Enabling CSM means that the computer will be *able* to boot a BIOS-mode OS -- but usually, enabling CSM doesn't *guarantee* a BIOS-mode boot; other factors determine whether the computer boots in BIOS mode. Secure Boot, by contrast, is mutually exclusive with a BIOS-mode boot; Secure Boot requires that all EFI boot loaders be signed with a private encryption key whose public counterpart is stored in the computer's NVRAM. Note that many EFIs permit enabling both CSM and Secure Boot; the firmware decides how to boot depending on what it finds on the hard disk and what its boot order settings are. Some EFIs, though, block BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boots if Secure Boot is active.

Thus, by disabling the CSM option, you've simply ruled out the possibility of booting Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. This is probably a good thing, since Windows 8 is almost always installed in EFI mode, and mixing boot modes across two OSes can get tricky. The "binary is whitelisted" message you got, though, indicates that Secure Boot is still enabled on your computer. (If it were disabled, `shim` would instead produce a message to that effect.)

Unfortunately, Ubuntu's Secure Boot support is based on an early version of `shim`, and I've seen quite a few reports of problems with that support. Thus, my initial suggestion is to go back into your firmware setup utility, find the options that control Secure Boot, and disable it.

Another thing to try is a firmware update. Sadly, many EFIs are buggy; but the better manufacturers, including ASUS, have been issuing frequent bug-fix updates. Thus, it's possible that updating your firmware will get you past this hurdle.

If neither of those suggestions help, then it gets trickier. Replacing GRUB on your Ubuntu install medium with [another EFI boot loader](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders) is a possibility, but this is likely to be a significant challenge if you're not already familiar with EFI boot loader installation. It's also much harder on CD/DVD media than on a USB flash drive. Another option would be to go into the firmware, enable a CSM-mode boot, and install Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. You can then install an EFI boot loader for Linux on your hard disk, which might be easier to get working than doing it on the Ubuntu install medium.